# Binding sub class object to spring mvc jsp views

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, view

How to bind a sub class object to a form in spring mvc jsp view ?

Example :

```
public class Group
{
public List<Animal> animals;
//other propertys
}


abstract class Animal
{
String name;
}

class lion extends animal
{
String legs;
}
```

How to bind the Group object to a jsp view ?

If cannot use this  `<c:forEach items="${group.animals}" var="animal">`  as it is throwing me an exception.

The exception I am receiving is

```
Could not instantiate property type [Animal] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Comment: Have you put `group` in the model attributes or the request attributes?

Comment: Do you have a getter for the `animals` field?

Comment: You're going to have to post more. Show us The full classes, how you put the `group` object into your model and how you expect to get it out from the request.

Answer (score 0):

The [EL engine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) used to parse `${groups.animals}` expects the object identified by `groups` to have a getter method called `getAnimals()`.

You call should look something like this

```
public class Group
{
    public List<Animal> animals;
    public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can display it to the user but when i bind it back it is throwing me errors during mapping. It cannot instantiate the appropriate sub class object

Comment: @SandeepRao Please always post your errors and your handler methods.

Comment: I have added the exception